# Unable to install SQL Server 2017 driver for PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, php-extension

I learned from video tutorial how to install SQL Server 2017 for PHP - and i did exactly like the tutorial said-but I still can't see the extension inside PHP Info list.

I installed:

PHP Version 7.1.9 
Xampp Server v3.2.2
Microsoft SQL Server 2017
SQL Native Client

I added the files with the names:

```
;extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

into my php.ini file , and ofcourse that i puted them into my ext directory also.

This is my SQL Info Output:

```
PHP Version 7.1.9
System  Windows NT DESKTOP-JTKEMP6 10.0 build 15063 (Windows 10) i586
Build Date  Aug 30 2017 18:33:21
Compiler    MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20160303
PHP Extension   20160303
Zend Extension  320160303
Zend Extension Build    API320160303,TS,VC14
PHP Extension Build API20160303,TS,VC14
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*
Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
Configuration
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    postmaster@localhost
Hostname:Port   localhost:80
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root C:/xampp/apache
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install php individually. Xampp includes php by default.

Stop xampp server and uncomment this lines your php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

and start xampp again.

Comment: i need to install Microsoft SQL Server driver not PHP .  Becuase i want integrate SuiteCRM With  Microsoft SQL Server 2017 DataBase